# Access 2013 Web app - Related Items control breaks

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, office365

Related Items control(s) works when created from scratch and not modified.
Adding a new tab to an existing control breaks existing tabs, the new tab works.

Adding a new Related Items control to a view breaks the existing control(s), the new control works.
All Related Items controls in a view must be built in the same operation - and even this is not reliable.

By 'breaks' I mean displays the message 'There was a problem loading data for this tab' instead of loading data.

Is there a fix?

I'm experimenting at the moment with only a few tables but I  have ~60 related tables to display in my main view and plan on using 6 to 10 Related Items controls to categorize them - it is painful to think that I would have to rebuild all the Related Items controls to make a small change.

Edit: Since 10 minutes ago when I wrote this I have added multiple Related Items controls (with one table in each) with no problem.

Edit: 1 hour later. I added more and it broke again.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8yev41hex27i6b/Screenshot%202015-02-19%2014.13.03.png?dl=0
???????? How can I trust it?

Edit: A few more hours later - sometimes they don't have 'Add xxxx' at the bottom either.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vx7vb40g1931r98/Screenshot%202015-02-19%2017.16.12.png?dl=0

Thanks.
Reuben